# How to push the button to the bottom of the card?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have built a plain HTML & CSS Page & built my own card component using flex box.

If you observe the images here, ***the button 'read more' is not aligning itself to the other card components to the bottom***: [image: Card Button Allignment-1] [image: Card Button Allignment-2]

In what way I can alter the code (using flexbox only) so that all "read More" buttons will appear on a single line **i.e Pushed to the bottom of the card component ??**

```css
    .container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .main-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .entry {
        flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 1rem);
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .entry .content {
        padding: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    h3 {
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .content h3 {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
    }
    
    .content span {
        color: #db008d;
    }
    
    .button {
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .6rem 2rem;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .content {
        /*What to write here ?? */
    }
```

```html
 <main class="main-content">
                <article class="entry">
                    <img src="img/01.jpg" alt="entry image">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Tips for Saving Money in your Next Travel</h3>
                        <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
                        <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
                        <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="entry">
                    <img src="img/02.jpg" alt="entry image">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>The Complete Guide for Traveling</h3>
                        <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
                        <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
                        <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="entry">
                    <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="entry image">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Ultimate Guide to Take the best Pictures</h3>
                        <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
                        <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
                        <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in `h3` and `p` in the `content`. they resize according to text wrap. so just define a fixed height for them.

```
.content h3 , p {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.entry {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 1rem);
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
}

.entry .content {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.content h3 {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.content span {
    color: #db008d;
}

.button {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .6rem 2rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

.content {
    /*What to write here ?? */
}

.content h3 , p {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-content">
    <article class="entry">
        <img src="img/01.jpg" alt="entry image">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Tips for Saving Money in your Next Travel</h3>
            <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
            <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="entry">
        <img src="img/02.jpg" alt="entry image">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>The Complete Guide for TravelingTravelingTraveling</h3>
            <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
            <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="entry">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="entry image">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Ultimate Guide to Take the best Pictures</h3>
            <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
            <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </article>
</main>
```

Comment: @Mad7Dragon...I tried it out..! It is also one possible solution. Thank you soo much for responding...! I wanted it to be more flexible....! The below answer was much suited where i made entire <article> tag area as a flex box & justified its content area.  With this, all cards expand to equal size...!

And the button will automatically come to bottom.

Comment: It's ok, don't forget to upvote. Also, your question was to just put buttons at the bottom. and that's what I did. good luck.

Comment: Sure, Did the upvote. feedback has been recorded. But as i do not have enough reputation not getting displayed. Thank you once again..!

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, you need to make `.entry` a flexbox column container and apply proper justification to its child elements: `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
* {
  outline: 1px dashed
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.entry {
  /* ADDED */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /**/

  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 1rem);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.entry .content {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.content h3 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.content span {
  color: #db008d;
}

.button {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .6rem 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  /*What to write here ?? */
}
```

```html
<main class="main-content">
  <article class="entry">
    <img src="img/01.jpg" alt="entry image">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Tips for Saving Money in your Next Travel</h3>
      <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
      <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
      <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="entry">
    <img src="img/02.jpg" alt="entry image">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>The Complete Guide for Traveling</h3>
      <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
      <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
      <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="entry">
    <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="entry image">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Ultimate Guide to Take the best Pictures</h3>
      <p>Published on: <span>July 19th, 2019</span></p>
      <p>By: <span>The Travel Blog</span></p>
      <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: The answer was bang on...! Thank you!

Comment: So the the issue was not in the content area, but was in the parent <article> tag area..As i make them flex & justified them all cards became equal size..??

Comment: @BalajiKR essentially, yes. The `* { outline ... }` showed that your cards differed in size causing the unequal positioning of the buttons at line breaks of other elements. The `space-between` forces the top element (`img`) and the bottom element (`.button`) to the upper respective lower margins of their flexbox parent. This is especially convenient in 'header/footer' situations. You might want to fiddle with `flex: 1` of child elements of `.entry` and see what the effect is.

Answer (score 0):

```html
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}
.parent .child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
  position:relative;
}
.parent .child .content {
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em gray;
}
.content img{
 background-size:cover;
 width:100%;
}
.content h3,p{
padding:10px;
}
.content input{
position:absolute;
bottom:5px;
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top:10px;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
      <div>
        <img  src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"/>
        <h3> test 3</h3>
        <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>  
        </div>
         <div><input type="button" value="click" /></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">  
       <div>
         <img  src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"/>
         <h3> test 2</h3>
         <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text tex </p>
        </div>
         <div><input type="button" value="click" /></div> 
     </div>
 </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">
       <div>
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"/>
         <h3> test 1</h3>
         <p>text text  text text text text text text text text text text tex</p>  
       </div>
       <div><input type="button" value="click" /></div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

please check this.....